# How to use sub dictionary in Mantle with Overcoat?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, github-mantle, overcoat

I decided to use Mantle to consume some JSON endpoints, but the structure of the JSON is different depending on whether you're `GET`ing or `POST`ing an object. Take the users endpoint for instance:

When requesting a user you get a response similar to this:

```
{
    "random_meta_data": "whatever",
    "etc.": "etc.",
    "payload": {
        "username": "username",
        "email": "username@email.com",
        "etc.": "etc."
    }
}
```

When creating a user you need to send something like this:

```
{
    "username": "username",
    "email": "username@email.com",
    "etc.": "etc."
}
```

It's not a difficult problem to solve, but it seems like a common enough problem that `Mantle` should be able to solve it for you.

I know I could simply initialize the mantle model with `dictionary[@"payload"]`, but `Overcoat` is doing the mapping for me automatically and if I'm going to do that manually I'm not taking advantage of `Overcoat` anymore.

So I'm wondering if there is a standard way of solving this with `Mantle` and/or `Overcoat`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called an envelop response and you can read about how to deal with those in the `Overcoat` README.md:

https://github.com/Overcoat/Overcoat#envelop-and-error-responses

> Other services like App.net use an envelop response, which is a top level JSON response containing the data requested and additional metadata. For these kind of services, you must create your own OVCResponse subclass and specify the data key path.

```
@interface AppDotNetResponse : OVCResponse
...
@end

@implementation AppDotNetResponse
+ (NSString *)resultKeyPathForJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)JSONDictionary 
{
    return @"data";
}
@end
```

> You can then specify which response class to use in your client by overriding +responseClass.

```
+ (Class)responseClass {
    return [AppDotNetResponse class];
}
```